# How can I run a piece of code only once after focusin one of the fields

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

```
<form id="myForm">
<label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
<label for="mname">Middle name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="mname" name="mname"><br><br>
<label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
</form>
```

I want to run a piece of code only once when there is a focusin event in any one of these fields of form.
How can I do that?

Comment: you are probably looking for this .... https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can make a JavaScript function that contains your code then loop through each of the form elements and as a focus event

Like

```
function hi (){
//Do stuff, then if you don't want it to go again

    Array.from(myForm.children)
        . forEach (c => 
            c.removeEventListener("focus", hi)
        )
}

Array.from(myForm.children)
. forEach (c => 
    c.addEventListener("focus", hi)
)
```

Comment: The function should be executed only once for focusin event. Like if first field is focused then function should be executed thats it. After that for any of the focus event the function shouldn't get called

Comment: So it should be called once for each element, or once total, if any element is selected?

Comment: once total if any element is selected